My 1999 Tahoe won't pull in high gears, only in 1st and 2nd gear
Shifted fine parked it two days no high gears now

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not sure I understand your question? What have you done to troubleshoot the issue? Have you tried to shift it manually? What engine is in your Tahoe?

When you say pull do you mean drive normally, or that it won't tow a load?
